# How can I discretly derive $u_{n}=\sin(np)$ where $p>0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How can I discretly derive $u_{n}=\sin(np)$ where $p>0$? I would show that $u_{n+1}-u_{n}\sim\ p\cos(np)$ with $u_{n}=\sin(np)$.
How can I do that? I tried trigonometric formula and Taylor series but nothing worked.

Comment: What do you get using [$(4.21.7)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.21.E7)? (Assuming $p$ is small.)

Comment: yes, I tried this one, but my goal is then to make it diverge so p will diverge

Comment: Such an equivalent seems impossible, but my goal was to show that 2 norms of sequences were not equivalent and with the mean value theorem, I get an inequality that makes it diverge.